# Puppet iterate in template

Tags: puppet, ruby

In .pp file:

```
replication => [

{

  name  => 'local',

  url   => xyz,

  push  => ['refs/heads', 'refs/tags'],

},

{

  name  => 'github',

  url   => abc,

  push  => ['refs/heads', 'refs/tags'],

},

]
```

How to define template to output the replication.config file looks like below:

```
[remote "local"]

url  = abc

push = refs/heads

push = refs/tags



[remote "github"]

url  = abc

push = refs/heads

push = refs/tags
```

Comment: If this is for Gerrit, have you tried [one of the modules available in the Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=gerrit)?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you might look at the [Augeas INI file lens](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/inifile-aug.html) or Puppet 4's [iteration and loops](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_iteration.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a defined resource type based on a template and use [puppetlabs-concat](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat) to join two parts based on the same template into your desired replication.config.